# unsubscribing from events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

In WinForms can I use IDisposable implementation to unsubscribe the form events (like: Activated, Load, ContextMenuChanged, ....) to help the garbage collection?

---

**Unsubscribing at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)**

To prevent your event handler from being invoked when the event is raised, unsubscribe from the event. In order to prevent resource leaks, you should unsubscribe from events before you dispose of a subscriber object. Until you unsubscribe from an event, the multicast delegate that underlies the event in the publishing object has a reference to the delegate that encapsulates the subscriber's event handler. As long as the publishing object holds that reference, garbage collection will not delete your subscriber object.

Comment: definitely, disposing an object will remove all subscriptions, that is assuming it is IDisposable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, but if the eventhandler is defined in your own class, and also defined in the same instance, then you do not have to unsubscribe from the event, since the publisher and subscriber are the same object. Therefore, no extra objects are held in reference.

If you subscribe object A to handle an event of object B, then it **is** worth to unsubscribe from the event in object B. Otherwise the multicast delegate that underlies the event will hold references to both objects. And that **will** prevent the garbage collector from collecting both objects.

Comment: @Groo Thanx. I didn't know it was a rule of thumb, but it's simply my own experience in the matter.

Answer (score 4):

Yep you can, however, depending on how many events there are I'd say this would come under the micro-optimization category.

Comment: I wouldn't say it has anything to do with performance. Leaving a handler attached prevents collection of the attached method's parent object. You don't need to detach from your own events (but in most cases you shouldn't even attach to them but instead override `OnXXX` methods), but if you are handling other objects' events, then it's important to unsubscribe when you are finished handling them.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [@Maarten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18850174/69809), instead of handling "your own" events inside a `Form`, it's usually much simpler to override any of the numerous `protected virtual` methods which invoke those events.

I.e. instead of attaching to a `Load` event:

```
this.Load += DoStuff;

private void DoStuff(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // do stuff
}
```

you should simply override the `OnLoad` method, removing the need to think about unsubscribing at all:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff
    ...

    // call the base method to fire the event 
    // for external listeners
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

This leaves you with handlers for only external objects' events, which should be detached when you're finished using them.

This is also why it's a good practice to always have a `protected virtual OnXXXX` method for each of your public events: to allow derived classes to fire the event and add additional handling logic before doing it.

Answer (score 1):

In the usual WinForms use case, the publishers and subscribers stick together and are disposed at the same time. A subscription to a buttons OnClick event is usually a method of the window class that contains the button. It would make no sense to remove the window from memory without also removing the button.

In these cases you don't need to unsubscribe (as far as I can tell).

It only matters if your subscriber classes are disposed of before the publisher does, e.g. another window reacting to a window's OnLoad. Then using IDisposable would be a good idea.